# Cannot set child view's size (height and width) larger than their parent

Tags: java, android, android-view

I need to be able to add a view that has a larger size than their parent. What I am trying to do is to set the view's size to the length of a short bond paper (8.5 x 11 inches) on any screen using TypedValue then I have a zoom view that scales this view so that I can see the whole once I zoomed out therefore I'm not able to use ScrollView. The problem is that android's measure pass doesn't let me to do so. The things I have tried are:

1. Setting LayoutParams width and height to 8.5x11 inches would result to the view being clipped and when I check the width and height of this child view it only returns the width and height of its parent.
2. Setting parent.setClipChildren(false) parent.setClipToPadding(false)
3. Overriding onMeasure

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
       super.onMeasure(width, height);
   }
   ```

   or this

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
       super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
   }
   ```

   then setting the width and height to layout params, however the parent view resizes larger than the child which I cannot have.

I just really need a child that has larger size than its parent so that when I add a view there it would look like it's scaled down. The UI looks like Microsoft Word with a page in the middle. Let me know if this is possible, if not then I think I should manually scale everything that's added to this 8.5x11 view.

I hope I made it clear. Thanks!